# Hangparas environment makes text go off the page

Tags: environments

I've been manually making a bibliography by using the hangparas environment from the [hanging](https://ctan.org/pkg/hanging) environment, but the text runs off the page. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaVPE.jpg) is what it looks like when I compile. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 

\usepackage{hanging} 

\begin{document} 
    text 

    \begin{hangparas}{0.5in}{1} 
        Allen, Barry. ``Chan Buddhism." In \textit{Vanishing into Things}, 140-65. Cambridge, Massachusetts; London, England: Harvard University Press, 2015. Accessed August 13, 2020. www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1c84dn5.7.
        
        Hershock, Peter. ``Chan Buddhism." \textit{Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy}. Stanford University, March 2, 2019. Last modified March 2, 2019. Accessed August 13, 2020. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-chan/.
        
        Sharf, Robert. "Mindfulness and Mindlessness in Early Chan." \textit{Philosophy East and West} 64, no. 4 (2014): 933-64. Accessed August 13, 2020. www.jstor.org/stable/43285932.
        
        Wang, Youru. "Liberating Oneself from the Absolutized Boundary of Language: A Liminological Approach to the Interplay of Speech and Silence in Chan Buddhism." \textit{Philosophy East and West} 51, no. 1 (2001): 83-99. Accessed August 13, 2020. www.jstor.org/stable/1400037.
        
        Y\"u, Ch\"un-fang. ``The Meditation Tradition: Chan Buddhism." In \textit{Chinese Buddhism: A Thematic History}, 172-97. Honolulu: University of Hawai'i Press, 2020. Accessed August 13, 2020. doi:10.2307/j.ctv105b9zz.11.
        
        Zong, Desheng. ``Three Language-Related Methods in Early Chinese Chan Buddhism." \textit{Philosophy East and West} 55, no. 4 (2005): 584-602. Accessed August 13, 2020. www.jstor.org/stable/4487989.
    \end{hangparas}
\end{document}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or something that I'm missing?

P.S. I know I should be using BibLaTeX/baber or some other bibliography-making tools, but I currently don't have the time to sit down and learn how to use those tools. I'd just like to resolve this problem now, get the assignment over with, and learn how to use BibLaTeX later.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{url}` to your preamble then using `\url{…}` with your URLs. This will enable the URLs to break across lines.

Comment: @DavidPurton that didn't work :(

Comment: Your picture doesn't match your sample document. You clearly have some hidden settings that prevent hyphenation, notably of "liminological". I agree with @Fran that the hanging you get with `{thebibliography}` is fine. You can do `\makeatletter \renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1}` to get rid of the brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know I should be using BibLaTeX/baber

Do you know also `thebibliography` environment? It is just to make the bibliography manually, without packages nor external files, with hang indentation but labelled\numbered automatically, and allow cross-references in text with key of the references, and print the header automatically.

The cite are always within `[]` (e.g.: `[23]` or `[Simth05]` if there are a label "Simth05" in the `\bibitem`), but the example below show a dirty trick to use parenthesis.

With `hyperref` you can also make the cites active links, and use also the `\url{}`
command, making also the URL active links, and  moreover, as David Purton suggested, solving the problem of the some long URL invading the right margin:

The next example show how to cite the references with a fake author-year (label) style or as numbers (of course, mixed only for demonstration purposes).

> [image: mwe]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}\setcitestyle{numbers} % dirty trick to change [] to  () 
\begin{document} 

Some numeric cites about Buddhism \cite{Hershock2019} or whatever \cite{Sharf2014,Wang2001}. Some author-year cites about meditation text \cite{Yu2020} and Buddhism \cite{Barry2015, Zong2005}.
 
\begin{thebibliography}{xxx} 
 
\bibitem{Hershock2019} Hershock, Peter. Chan Buddhism.\textit{Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy}. Stanford University, March 2, 2019. Last modified March 2, 2019. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-chan/}.
        
\bibitem{Sharf2014} Sharf, Robert. "Mindfulness and Mindlessness in Early Chan. \textit{Philosophy East and West} 64, no. 4 (2014): 933-64. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/43285932}.
        
\bibitem{Wang2001} Wang, Youru. Liberating Oneself from the Absolutized Boundary of Language: A Liminological Approach to the Interplay of Speech and Silence in Chan Buddhism. \textit{Philosophy East and West} 51, no. 1 (2001): 83-99. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/1400037}.

\bibitem[Barry,~2015]{Barry2015} Allen, Barry. Chan Buddhism. In \textit{Vanishing into Things}, 140-65. Cambridge, Massachusetts; London, England: Harvard University Press, 2015. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1c84dn5.7.}
        
\bibitem[Zong,~2005]{Zong2005} Zong, Desheng. Three Language-Related Methods in Early Chinese Chan Buddhism. \textit{Philosophy East and West} 55, no. 4 (2005): 584-602. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/4487989}.

\bibitem[Yü,~2020]{Yu2020} Yü, Chü-fang. The Meditation Tradition: Chan Buddhism.In \textit{Chinese Buddhism: A Thematic History}, 172-97. Honolulu: University of Hawaii Press, 2020. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{doi:10.2307/j.ctv105b9zz.11}.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note:

As one comment about brackets is from author of the `cite` package,  here is an alternative method to use `natbib`, that change brackets also in references:

```
\usepackage[biblabel]{cite}
\renewcommand\citeleft{(}
\renewcommand\citeright{)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be using a bibliography tool such as Biber or BibTeX.

Anyway, the main problem for you are the URLs.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text

\bigskip

\begin{hangparas}{0.5in}{1} 
Allen, Barry. ``Chan Buddhism.'' In \textit{Vanishing into Things}, 140-65. 
Cambridge, Massachusetts; London, England: Harvard University Press, 2015. 
Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/j.ctt1c84dn5.7}.

Hershock, Peter. ``Chan Buddhism.'' \textit{Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy}. 
Stanford University, March 2, 2019. Last modified March 2, 2019. Accessed August 13, 2020. 
\url{https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/buddhism-chan/}.

Sharf, Robert. ``Mindfulness and Mindlessness in Early Chan.'' \textit{Philosophy East and West} 
64, no. 4 (2014): 933-64. Accessed August 13, 2020. \url{www.jstor.org/stable/43285932}.

Wang, Youru. ``Liberating Oneself from the Absolutized Boundary of Language: A Liminological 
Approach to the Interplay of Speech and Silence in Chan Buddhism.'' 
\textit{Philosophy East and West} 51, no. 1 (2001): 83-99. Accessed August 13, 2020. 
\url{www.jstor.org/stable/1400037}.

Y\"u, Ch\"un-fang. ``The Meditation Tradition: Chan Buddhism.'' In 
\textit{Chinese Buddhism: A Thematic History}, 172-97. 
Honolulu: University of Hawai'i Press, 2020. Accessed August 13, 2020. 
\url{doi:10.2307/j.ctv105b9zz.11}.

Zong, Desheng. ``Three Language-Related Methods in Early Chinese Chan Buddhism.'' 
\textit{Philosophy East and West} 55, no. 4 (2005): 584-602. Accessed August 13, 2020. 
\url{www.jstor.org/stable/4487989}.
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

With `xurl`, any point is good for breaking a URL.

[image]

You should also be consistent with quotes:

```
`` opening
'' closing
```